# Keras: How to get the initial_state of GRU

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have already defined a GRU using Keras, How to get the initial_state (h_0) of the GRU ?    Any help will be appreciated！

Answer (score 1):

There is a state list in the layer

```
gru_layer_number = 2 # order of definition
model.layers[gru_layer_number].states
```

You can define the initial state with the `initial_state` parameter as the [documentation says](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm).

There is also a [`get_initial_state()`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L432) function you can check (haven't tested it)